# Any Direct Policy Search textbooks?

Tags: references, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to data science and machine learning. I've been tasked with understanding DPS. So far, I know that it is a part of Reinforcement Learning but I can't find anything specific to DPS other that very technical scholar journals and papers on it. Are there any textbooks specific to DPS or even RL that has a subtopic dedicated to DPS?

PS: Any suggestions on what to read to improve my mathematics as well? More to, what I need to read in order to understand mathematics in DPS papers.

Comment: This looks like an on topic request for references to me. I don't see why it would be *too broad*. I'm voting to leave open.